# Reading of a char contained in a struct results in access violation exception

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

i am trying to implement a linked-list in C with the aim to do a BFS on it.
The input for the list should look like this:

```
a-bc
b-a
c-a
```

which represents a list looking like this:

```
 a
/ \
b  c
```

now, my problem is that I cannot read the variable `name` defined in my `Vertex` struct. My program segfaults with Access Reading Violation. While `printf("%s", s)` takes a `char *`, casting the `name` to a `char*` doesn't help. The error takes place before the char is even accessed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Vertex Vertex;

typedef struct Vertex
{
    char name;
    int visited;
    int distance;
    Vertex* next;
} Vertex;

struct Vertex* AddVertex(Vertex* head, char newVertexName)
{
    Vertex* newHead = malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
    newHead->name = newVertexName;
    printf("added vertex named: %s", newHead->name); // causing the error
    newHead->next = head;
    newHead->visited = 0;
    newHead->distance = 0;
    return newHead;
}

int main()
{
    // BFS
    char s[100];
    int l = 0;
    const int nNrOfVerts = 27;
    Vertex* adjList[28];

    // initialise array of pointers
    for(int i = 0; i <= nNrOfVerts; ++i)
    {
        adjList[i] = NULL;
    }

    // fill vertices with user data
    for(int i = 1; i <= nNrOfVerts; ++i)
    {
        printf("enter %d vert: ", i);
        if(scanf("%s", &s) != 1)
        {
            break;
        }

        l = strlen(s);
        if(l > 2)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < l; ++k)
            {
                // increment to accustom for the - seperator
                if(1 == k)
                {
                    k = 2;
                }

                adjList[i] = AddVertex(adjList[i], s[k]);
            }
        }

        for(int k = 0; k < 100; ++k)
        {
            s[k] = NULL;
        }
    }

    bfs(adjList);

    // printing the list
    for(int i = 1; i <= l; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= nNrOfVerts; ++j)
        {
            if(adjList[j]->distance == i)
            {
                printf("Level: %d is: %s", i, adjList[j]->name);
            }
            printf("No node for dist: %d", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I access the value of newHead->name or adjList[i]->name for that matter? The interesting thing is, if I try to access adjList[i]->distance the correct integer is returned...

Comment: Use `%c` instead of `%s`.

Comment: you should check warning first. there are lot of issue in your code. you declared char s[100], and scanf("%s",&s).. what are you going to get? you are define s[k]=NULL,... how can you do it? Before asking question, Do check warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `name` as a `char` but then you try to print it as a character :

```
printf("added vertex named: %s", newHead->name);
```

Change the `%s` to `%c` :

```
printf("added vertex named: %c", newHead->name);
```

or change your name to a `char *`.